# Basic question about finding mRNA sequence in transcriptome

Tags: sam, fasta, samtools, transcriptome

I am a computer scientist just starting out in bioinformatics topics, and would appreciate any guidance that can be given here:

I have an [mRNA sequence](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NM_000551.4)- an isoform - whose length is about 4000 base pairs (bp) - the origin is provided in the link.

I also have a [bam file/fasta file](https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/?run=SRR10377489) of the entire transcriptome of a kidney cell (see Data Access tab).

My objective is to quantify mRNA expression levels of the mRNA sequence in the transcriptome.

How does one get started? Should I use the original format (TenX bam, about 10 GB) or SRA archive data (fasta, about 3.5 GB)?  Why are the files so different in size?

I have a MacBook with `samtools` installed and 16GB of RAM. Is this enough to process the data and what basic commands should be used to quantify the 4000 bp sequence overlaps in the transcriptome?

Comment: Hi @the_darkside this isn't what we do. The package you need IMHO is called `Seurat`, it would be recommneded that you read the manual and return with specific technical questions.

Comment: Right.  Looking up gene counts for a single gene in a single sample, it's pretty useless. Especially on a single cell experiment, which is complicated.  Is this really a class assignment?

Comment: I know that looking at a single gene in a single cell sample is not very useful in and of itself, but the idea is to get some practice in mRNA quantification.  I hope that once I understand the process, I can repeat the process on tissue samples.  I haven't yet been able to find an available file of non-single cell mRNA sequencing of a human kidney.

Comment: This is not how you do it.  Find a bulk RNASeq sample, and go through a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want to know the VHL Gene expression in that 10x dataset. They have provided the barcode, matrix and feature files on GEO [GSE131685](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE131685) as Supplementary file. You could use those files and get the gene expression matrix as described on [10x website](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/output/matrices).

```
library(Matrix)

matrix_dir = "/opt/sample345/outs/filtered_feature_bc_matrix/"
barcode.path <- paste0(matrix_dir, "barcodes.tsv.gz")
features.path <- paste0(matrix_dir, "features.tsv.gz")
matrix.path <- paste0(matrix_dir, "matrix.mtx.gz")

mat <- readMM(file = matrix.path)

feature.names = read.delim(features.path, 
                           header = FALSE,
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

barcode.names = read.delim(barcode.path, 
                           header = FALSE,
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colnames(mat) = barcode.names$V1
rownames(mat) = feature.names$V1
```

This mat can be further loaded into [Seurat](https://satijalab.org/seurat/) for any downstream analysis. All this can be done on a laptop.

If you want to re-quantify the gene expression for whatever the reason, you need to re-run the cellRanger pipeline using GTF of your interest (it needs some [preparation](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/using/tutorial_mr)), which may not work on your laptop. It requires large memory and long running times, ideally to submit as job on cluster.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use the original format (TenX bam, about 10 GB) or SRA
> archive data (fasta, about 3.5 GB)? Why are the files so different in
> size?

I strongly recommend you hold your horses; how do you think you can analyze something if you don't even know what you are looking at?

Since this is a "TenX" bam, you can probably do the job with samtools and grep.  Looking up 10XGenomics bam tags might be helpful.  You might need to look up SAM flags too.

> My objective is to quantify mRNA expression levels of the mRNA
> sequence in the transcriptome.

You understand that this isn't really a thing that's possible?  With spike-ins, maybe, but you don't have that.  All you can do is work out the proportions of reads belonging to that transcript  (Or gene, really, unless you want to put in a great deal more work, beyond I believe what 10XGenomics does).  Which I guess you want to do by lumping all the cells together, and just pretending there is no QC to do?